# Improve TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, tikz-styles

My program is the following one, but, as you can see, I get two errors (`Missing $ Inserted`) probably because I shouldn't use the `cases` environment here. If so, what is my alternative?
Also, any other suggestions for esthetic improvements?

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\a{4} 
        \path[nodes={ellipse,draw}]
        (\a,-\a/4)  node (W) {
        $$s''
        \begin{cases}
            r' = 0.4\\
            r'' = 0.6
        \end{cases}$$}
        (0,0)  node (F) {s,a}
        (\a,\a/4) node (Y) {
        $$s'
        \begin{cases}
            r' = 0.2\\
            r'' = 0.8
        \end{cases}$$}
        ;
        \begin{scope}[-latex]
            \draw (F) to[bend right] node[below]{$0.7$} (W);
            \draw (F) to[bend left]  node[above]{$0.3$} (Y);
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example model}
    \label{ex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Using indenting of code lines is a proven way of error-reduction (defensive programming) .

Comment: Please add a verbal description to your question (Edit) of what your image should look like and/or what you do in the tikz part.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot use `$$` environment inside nodes. Here you have an alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{4} 
% \path[nodes={circle,draw,fill=yellow!50,minimum size=18mm}]
\path[nodes={ellipse,draw}]
(\a,-\a/4)  node (W) {
$s''\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
r' &= 0.4\\
r'' &= 0.6
\end{array}\right.$}
(0,0)  node (F) {s,a}
(\a,\a/4) node (Y) {
$s'
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
r' &= 0.2\\
r'' &= 0.8
\end{array}\right.$}
;
\begin{scope}[-latex]
\draw (F) to[bend right] node[below]{$0.7$} (W);
\draw (F) to[bend left]  node[above]{$0.3$} (Y);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]